# Do I Need to Hash My Passwords for Keycloak Client?

Tags: java, keycloak

I'm using `org.keycloak:keycloak-admin-client:12.0.4`. I've been doing some research about how to use the API.

Here are a couple examples:

```java
        // ----
        // Getting a JWT
        // ----
        Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                .serverUrl("http://localhost:8180/auth")
                .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD)
                .realm("dev")
                .clientId("example-client")
                .clientSecret("1169ef64-ea8f-47eb-9e55-74fdda9ee398")
                .username("user1")
                // raw password
                .password("user1Pass")
                .resteasyClient(
                        new ResteasyClientBuilderImpl()
                                .connectionPoolSize(10).build()
                ).build();

        AccessTokenResponse atr =
                keycloak.tokenManager().getAccessToken();

        // ----
        // Creating a new user
        // ----
        UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
        user.setEnabled(true);
        user.setUsername("tester1");
        user.setFirstName("First");
        user.setLastName("Last");
        user.setEmail("example@email.com");
        user.setAttributes(Collections.singletonMap("origin", Arrays.asList("demo")));

        RealmResource realmResource = keycloak.realm("dev");
        UsersResource usersRessource = realmResource.users();

        Response response = usersRessource.create(user);
        String userId = CreatedResponseUtil.getCreatedId(response);

        CredentialRepresentation passwordCred = new CredentialRepresentation();
        passwordCred.setTemporary(false);
        passwordCred.setType(CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD);
        // raw password
        passwordCred.setValue("test");

        UserResource userResource = usersRessource.get(userId);
```

So in both of these situations, I'm using a `String` which is the raw password. My question is, should I be hashing passwords before sending them to Keycloak?

It's not that I distrust Keycloak, I'm just curious if Keycloak itself is doing some hashing in its own implementation. I've done some searching on Google, but haven't found any what I'm looking for.

Comment: When you invoke OAuth `/token` endpoint (Direct auth) you must pass encoded password. I think your Builder does it for you. I saw no ways to send hashed pwd via direct flow, I think it's only for browser auth

Comment: Gotcha. So just to make sure I understand, if I invoke the rest API directly I'll need to encode the password. But if I use the Java client (and thus the builder) it will encode the passwords for me? Do you know if, in Keycloak's database on the server, that the passwords are encoded?